# Pyinstaller executable "Cannot open self x or archive x.pkg"

Tags: python, macos, cron, pyinstaller, apple-m1

I used pyinstaller to create an executable file for a Python script on my M1 mac. The script runs fine from command line or by just clicking on it, but when it's executed from a crontab I get the error `Cannot open self x or archive x.pkg` where `x` is the file path. I've searched around extensively but am yet to find a single solution. I have the feeling it has to do with some disparity between the pyinstaller architecture and the M1, but I don't understand why that wouldn't interfere with me running from the command line and would cause problems only via cron. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a MAC with an intel, but I added '.app' to the executable name and this worked for me.